# .Net - Mapping filters to URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Java, it is possible to associate a specific filter to a specific URL, using the web.xml  tag.

Is the same possible in .Net?

I did a Google search, and all I got was folks suggesting to use `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url` to find out if the filter was applicable. However, we have a filter which we need for only certain URL patterns, and hence we would like to do URL specific filters.

Comment: I'm confused by the concept of a *filter*? What's this *filter* supposed to do?

Comment: @Liam, This link should probably help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647251.aspx

Comment: I think you want the [Routing provided by the global.asax](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)